# CRXJS Error: Path contains invalid characters when running chrome extension

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, vite, browser-extension

I cloned the chrome extension quickstart from [this site](https://reactjsexample.com/react-typescript-starter-for-developing-web-currently-only-chrome-extensions-with-hot-reload/), however I am unable to run it after installing the dependencies (with yarn). I am using Node 16 via NVM as Node-Gyp was giving some installation errors on Node 18. When I run "yarn dev" I get the following output after Vite initializes the local dev server:

```
PS C:\Users\kking\OneDrive\Documents\code\Client Projects\refine3\refine-v3> yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.19
warning ..\package.json: No license field
$ run-s clean && vite
warning ..\package.json: No license field
$ run-p clean:*
warning ..\package.json: No license field
warning ..\package.json: No license field
$ rimraf dist
$ rimraf dist-firefox-v2

  VITE v4.3.9  ready in 881 ms        

  ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:5173/  
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose    
  ➜  press h to show help
C:\Users\kking\OneDrive\Documents\code\Client Projects\refine3\refine-v3\node_modules\@crxjs\vite-plugin\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\utils.js:16   
      const error = new Error(`Path contains invalid characters: ${pth}`)   
                    ^

Error: Path contains invalid characters: C:/Users/kking/OneDrive/Documents/code/Client Projects/refine3/refine-v3/src/C:\Users\kking\OneDrive\Documents\code\Client Projects\refine3\refine-v3\dist/content
    at checkPath (C:\Users\kking\OneDrive\Documents\code\Client Projects\refine3\refine-v3\node_modules\@crxjs\vite-plugin\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\utils.js:16:21)
    at Object.module.exports.makeDir (C:\Users\kking\OneDrive\Documents\code\Client Projects\refine3\refine-v3\node_modules\@crxjs\vite-plugin\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\make-dir.js:12:3)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (C:\Users\kking\OneDrive\Documents\code\Client Projects\refine3\refine-v3\node_modules\universalify\index.js:22:13)  
    at C:\Users\kking\OneDrive\Documents\code\Client Projects\refine3\refine-v3\node_modules\@crxjs\vite-plugin\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\output-file\index.js:20:11
    at C:\Users\kking\OneDrive\Documents\code\Client Projects\refine3\refine-v3\node_modules\universalify\index.js:22:54 {
  code: 'EINVAL'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I initially thought the issue was due to running from a Onedrive-synced folder, so I ran it from a different folder but had the same result. I have looked through the issues on CRXJS's repo, Vite's repo, and the repo for this quickstart but have not been able to find any posted issues mentioning this problem. [repo](https://github.com/sinanbekar/browser-extension-react-typescript-starter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone from the future viewing this, dont use that sites "quickstart" template. Just follow the official CRXJS documentation [here](https://crxjs.dev/vite-plugin/getting-started/react/create-project)